# Merge three xml document with different name spaces into one in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have 3 different xml Strings(Not Files Strings in JVM). Sample Given below

**A.xml**

```
<A namespace="A..">
<Document>
<Header>...</Header>
<Body>
</Body>
</Document>
</A>
```

**B.xml**

```
  <B namespace="B...">
    <BusinessHeader>
    ....
    </BusinessHeader>
    </B>
```

**C.xml**

```
<C namespace="C..">
<BusinessBody>

</BusinessBody>
</C>
```

I want the content of B and C to go inside the `<Body>` tag of A along with the namespaces. See `Result.xml`

**Result.xml**

```
  <A namespace="A..">
    <Document>
    <Header>...</Header>
    <Body>
    <B namespace="B...">
    <BusinessHeader>
    ....
    </BusinessHeader>
    </B>
    <C namespace="C..">
    <BusinessBody>

    </BusinessBody>
    </C>
    </Body>
    </Document>
    </A>
```

I tried doing this but I get the following error.

```
org.w3c.dom.Document a = convertStringToXml(transmissionReportPayload);
org.w3c.dom.Document b = convertStringToXml(headerPayLoad);
org.w3c.dom.Document c = convertStringToXml(documentPayload);


Node firstDocImportedNode = (Node) a.importNode(b, true);
a.appendChild(firstDocImportedNode );


StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

// print results
TransformerFactory.newInstance()
        .newTransformer()
        .transform(new DOMSource(a), new StreamResult(writer));

return  writer.toString();
```

I get the following the error.

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: The implementation does not support the requested type of object or operation. 

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.importNode(CoreDocumentImpl.java:1767)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.importNode(CoreDocumentImpl.java:1533)
    at za.co.fnb.gts.iso.simulator.pacs002.Pacs002ResponseConverter.createXML(Pacs002ResponseConverter.java:89)
    at za.co.fnb.gts.iso.simulator.pacs002.Pacs002ResponseConverter.convertPacs002ResponseToPayload(Pacs002ResponseConverter.java:73)
```

Comment: Is this a question or an assignment?

Comment: What is attribute namespace? To declare the default namespace you should use xmlns="...".

Answer (score 0):

You should use the document element instead of the document for `importNode()`.
Also for the target element.
Here a full example with `xmlns="..."` as the correct attribute to denote the default namespace.

```
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class ImportNode {
  private static final String XML_A = "<A namespace=\"http://a.example.com\">\n" +
    "<Document>\n" +
    "<Header>...</Header>\n" +
    "<Body>\n" +
    "</Body>\n" +
    "</Document>\n" +
    "</A>";
  private static final String XML_B = "<B xmlns=\"http://b.example.com\">\n" +
    "    <BusinessHeader>\n" +
    "    ....\n" +
    "    </BusinessHeader>\n" +
    "    </B>";

  private static Document convertStringToXml(String xmlString) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory fac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    fac.setNamespaceAware(true);
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
    InputSource source = new InputSource(reader);
    return fac.newDocumentBuilder().parse(source);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException, IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    Document a = convertStringToXml(XML_A);
    Document b = convertStringToXml(XML_B);

    Node firstDocImportedNode = (Node) a.importNode(b.getDocumentElement(), true);
    a.getDocumentElement().appendChild(firstDocImportedNode );

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    // print results
    TransformerFactory.newInstance()
        .newTransformer()
        .transform(new DOMSource(a), new StreamResult(writer));

    System.out.println(writer.toString());
  }
}
```

Output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><A namespace="http://a.example.com">
<Document>
<Header>...</Header>
<Body>
</Body>
</Document>
<B xmlns="http://b.example.com">
    <BusinessHeader>
    ....
    </BusinessHeader>
    </B></A>
```

Comment: But I want B inside the document element

Comment: Then you should adjust the code a little bit. First find document a's Document element. Then call `appendChild()` for it.